# Custom post type specific item design

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I  have a custom post type (benefits). Which as post name (bronze, silver, gold, diamond). All are listed in the same page template page-benefits.php. I want to display all on the same page but want to specific design for Diamond.
how I can achieve this while remaining in the same loop and same page template.

Comment: It will be better if you include your page template code. Without seeing the code none will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do so. Here is a simple solution for the loop-template:

```
<?php
// set css class, if post-title is 'diamond'
$cpt_class = ('diamond' === strtolower( $post->post_title ) ) ? 'post-is-diamond' : '';
?> 
<!-- Begin loop-template -->
<article <?php post_class( $cpt_class ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

... your stuff here ...

</article>
```

So only if the post-title is 'diamond', the article has the css class 'post-is-diamond'.